# Enumerate the primes using only unary arithmetic

Tags: code-golf, primes

Write a program which prints the sequence of prime numbers. The shortest solution wins!

All numbers must have a unary representation (not just in the output, but throughout the entire program). This could be a string of 1s, a list of 1s, Peano-style objects, etc.

No particular output format is required, as long as numbers are recognizable. `111`, `[1, 1, 1]`, and `S(S(S(0)))` are all acceptable representations of `3`, for example.

Examples of permissible operations:

- Appending or prepending a constant value to a string/list
- Deleting a constant number of elements from a string/list
- Comparing something with a constant, such as `"11"`
- Calling `is_empty` on a string/list

Examples of what's not allowed:

- Any operations on non-unary integers or floats, such as `+`, `%`, `==` or `<`
- Built-in functions which operate on multiple strings/lists, like `+` or `==`
- Importing or downloading a library which does unary arithmetic ;-)

Sample programs

- [Java, with Peano numbers](https://gist.github.com/dlubarov/7382360)
- [Python, with strings of 1s](https://gist.github.com/dlubarov/7382357)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Haskell, <strike>212</strike> <strike>135</strike> <strike>130</strike> <strike>111</strike> 104 characters

```
x⊡[1]=print x>>p x
x⊡s@(_:r)=s∇x where[]∇[]=p x;_∇[]=x⊡r;[]∇y=s∇y;(_:t)∇(_:y)=t∇y
p x=(1:x)⊡x
main=p[1]
```

The sieve was fun to implement, but simple exhaustive remainder checking is smaller. Strictly adheres to the terms. Unary numbers are represented as lists of 1.

First ten primes:

```
& runhaskell 13159-UnaryPrimes.hs | head
[1,1]
[1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

No library functions are used at all in the computation. In fact, the only library function used is `print`, which you can't get away from since you need some library function to output.

Answer (score 4):

### C, 220 chars

```
o(void**n){putchar(n?33:10);n&&o(*n);}
d(void**a,void**b,void**c){return a?d(*a,b,c?*c:*b):c;}
q(void**a,void**b){return a?q(*a,*b):b;}
p(a,s){return!q(&s,a)||d(a,&s,0)&&p(a,&s);}
z;
e(n){p(&n,&z)&&o(&n);e(&n);}
main(){e(&z);}
```

Explanations:

1. Numbers are represented as linked lists. `NULL` is 0, a pointer to `N` is `N+1`.
2. `e` enumerates numbers by calling itself with `&n`, i.e. with `n+1`. It uses `p` to test for primality and `o` to print.
3. `p(a,s)` tests if `a` is prime, checking divisors starting from `s`.
4. `q(a,b)` returns false if the numbers are equal. It only works for `a<=b`.
5. `d(a,b,0)` returns false if `b` divides `a`. The 3rd parameter is for recursion.
6. `o(n)` prints `n` exclamation marks, followed by a newline.

Comment: I get a segfault in the first `q` call when dereferencing `b`, though I haven't figured out why - it looks fine to me. I'm running `i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1`.

Comment: @Daniel, I can see why it would fail on 64bit, but `i686` means 32bit, right? Anyway, you can try adding `void *` to `z` and parameters in `p` and `e` (I saved precious characters by making them implicitly `int`, but they're actually pointers).

Answer (score 3):

### Perl 39 bytes

```
$_.=1while/^(11+)\1+$/||print$_||=11,$/
```

Interestingly enough, a well-known Perl primality test actually *relies* on unary logic.

Comment: Heh, I thought of this but couldn't think of a good rule to prohibit it. My intention was to exclude all built-in functions besides a few, like (if we're using Lisp) `cons` and `cdr`, which would exclude regex matching. But +1 since I didn't make that clear.

Comment: One might argue that the regex above uses 'variable length comparison', which seems to be at odds with specifically allowing constant comparison. By that logic, something like `/11/` would be allowed, but `/11+/` would not.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 81 chars

```
a=s@s@0;b={};While[1<2,Print@a;b~AppendTo~a;While[Or@@((a//.#:>0)==0&/@b),a=s@a]]
```

#### Output:

> s[s[0]]
> s[s[s[0]]]
> s[s[s[s[s[0]]]]]
> s[s[s[s[s[s[s[0]]]]]]]
> s[s[s[s[s[s[s[s[s[s[s[0]]]]]]]]]]]
> ......

#### Explanation:

Numbers are represented as Peano numbers. For example, `s[s[0]]` means `2`. I use suffix notation in my code. `s@s@0` is just short for `s[s[0]]`.

`a//.#:>0` repeatedly replace the pattern `#` in `a` with `0`. Both `a` and `#` in this expression are Peano numbers. In fact, it is equivalent to `a mod #`. For example, `s[s[s[0]]]]]//.s[s[0]]:>0` returns `s[0]`. So `(a//.#:>0)==0` if and only if `a` is divisible by `#`.

Comment: I didn't want string functions like find-and-replace to be used, but my fault for not making that clear. A nice solution in any case.

Answer (score -1):

### Action Script 3 | Many bytes

```
var endOfTheWorld:Object = new Object();
var timeToEndOfTheWorld:Number = 1;

while(!endOfTheWorld){
    var busted:boolean = false;
    timeToEndOfTheWorld++;

    for (var k:Object in endOfTheWorld) {
        if(timeToEndOfTheWorld % Number(k) == 0){
            busted = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(busted){
        continue;
    }

    timeToEndOfTheWorld[timeToEndOfTheWorld] = timeToEndOfTheWorld;
    trace(timeToEndOfTheWorld);
}
```

**P.S**
*If you think I got wrong with the time to end of the world, then prove it ;)*

Comment: This is just a stack of ordinary numbers, with explicit arithmetic operations: `++`, `%`, and `==`. The aim was to use Paeno or unary numbers, and to avoid all arithmetic operations built into the language.